# Is timestamp difference always INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

My observations show that timestamp difference has type of `INTERVAL DAY TO SECONDS`:

```sql
select typeof(getdate() - current_date())
-----------------------------------------
    
interval day to second
```

But is it guaranteed? Can it be `DAY TO MINUTE` or `YEAR TO MONTH` depending on the input? I could not find that in the documentation.

This becomes important when converting an interval to numeric format, since `CAST()` returns the number of *lower* units in the interval.

*P.S. I am aware of other ways to convert time delta into seconds.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [documented](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/minussign.html):

> If expr1 and expr2 are DATEs the result is an INTERVAL DAYS.
>
> If expr1 or expr2 are TIMESTAMP the result is an INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND.

It can be INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH only when subtracting two year-month intervals.

And I think you can't cast an interval to a number...